# Writing a script to show every permutations of a set of variables

Tags: perl, scripting, combinations

I am attempting to write a perl script which can figure out exactly how many permutations are possible from set of variables. The variables in question have a set number of options.

For example:

```
Var1 [Yes|No]
Var2 [Yes|No|Maybe]
Var3 [1|2|3|4]
Var4 [Yes|No]
Var5 [Yes|No|Maybe]
```

However, there are about 15 different variables, and these may change. Can anyone provide a general idea of what logic to use in order to find every permutation of this data set?

The only way I can think to do this is by storing everything in a data structure and using nested loops, but every time I try to write something it becomes a jumbled mess.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's possible, but SO is not a "I need this code" website. We'll help you with you code, but not produce what you request on demand.

Comment: @AntonH I understand, and am sorry. I'm just having trouble figuring out where to start. I would be happy with just being pointed in the right direction

Comment: It happens. Maybe give more detail on which part is giving you problems (String analysis, help with algorithm, ...). Give already your thought on a solution, even if it's very brief pseudo-code.

Comment: Please explain how your variables and their possible values are specified in the first place. Are you reading them from an initialisation file? Please also show an example of the output data that you require.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could just use simple recursion:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my @options = map {/\[(.*?)\]/ ? [split /\|/, $1] : die $_} <DATA>;

alloptions(\@options);

sub alloptions {
    my $options = shift;
    my $index = shift || 0;
    my $vals = shift || [];

    for my $val (@{ $options->[$index] }) {
        if ($index == $#$options) {
            print "@$vals $val\n";
        } else {
            alloptions($options, $index + 1, [@$vals, $val]);
        }
    }
}

__DATA__
Var1 [Yes|No]
Var2 [Yes|No|Maybe]
Var3 [1|2|3|4]
Var4 [Yes|No]
Var5 [Yes|No|Maybe]
```

Outputs:

```
Yes Yes 1 Yes Yes
Yes Yes 1 Yes No
Yes Yes 1 Yes Maybe
Yes Yes 1 No Yes
Yes Yes 1 No No
Yes Yes 1 No Maybe
Yes Yes 2 Yes Yes
Yes Yes 2 Yes No
Yes Yes 2 Yes Maybe
Yes Yes 2 No Yes
Yes Yes 2 No No
Yes Yes 2 No Maybe
Yes Yes 3 Yes Yes
Yes Yes 3 Yes No
Yes Yes 3 Yes Maybe
Yes Yes 3 No Yes
Yes Yes 3 No No
Yes Yes 3 No Maybe
Yes Yes 4 Yes Yes
Yes Yes 4 Yes No
Yes Yes 4 Yes Maybe
Yes Yes 4 No Yes
Yes Yes 4 No No
Yes Yes 4 No Maybe
Yes No 1 Yes Yes
Yes No 1 Yes No
Yes No 1 Yes Maybe
Yes No 1 No Yes
Yes No 1 No No
Yes No 1 No Maybe
Yes No 2 Yes Yes
Yes No 2 Yes No
Yes No 2 Yes Maybe
Yes No 2 No Yes
Yes No 2 No No
Yes No 2 No Maybe
Yes No 3 Yes Yes
Yes No 3 Yes No
Yes No 3 Yes Maybe
Yes No 3 No Yes
Yes No 3 No No
Yes No 3 No Maybe
Yes No 4 Yes Yes
Yes No 4 Yes No
Yes No 4 Yes Maybe
Yes No 4 No Yes
Yes No 4 No No
Yes No 4 No Maybe
Yes Maybe 1 Yes Yes
Yes Maybe 1 Yes No
Yes Maybe 1 Yes Maybe
Yes Maybe 1 No Yes
Yes Maybe 1 No No
Yes Maybe 1 No Maybe
Yes Maybe 2 Yes Yes
Yes Maybe 2 Yes No
Yes Maybe 2 Yes Maybe
Yes Maybe 2 No Yes
Yes Maybe 2 No No
Yes Maybe 2 No Maybe
Yes Maybe 3 Yes Yes
Yes Maybe 3 Yes No
Yes Maybe 3 Yes Maybe
Yes Maybe 3 No Yes
Yes Maybe 3 No No
Yes Maybe 3 No Maybe
Yes Maybe 4 Yes Yes
Yes Maybe 4 Yes No
Yes Maybe 4 Yes Maybe
Yes Maybe 4 No Yes
Yes Maybe 4 No No
Yes Maybe 4 No Maybe
No Yes 1 Yes Yes
No Yes 1 Yes No
No Yes 1 Yes Maybe
No Yes 1 No Yes
No Yes 1 No No
No Yes 1 No Maybe
No Yes 2 Yes Yes
No Yes 2 Yes No
No Yes 2 Yes Maybe
No Yes 2 No Yes
No Yes 2 No No
No Yes 2 No Maybe
No Yes 3 Yes Yes
No Yes 3 Yes No
No Yes 3 Yes Maybe
No Yes 3 No Yes
No Yes 3 No No
No Yes 3 No Maybe
No Yes 4 Yes Yes
No Yes 4 Yes No
No Yes 4 Yes Maybe
No Yes 4 No Yes
No Yes 4 No No
No Yes 4 No Maybe
No No 1 Yes Yes
No No 1 Yes No
No No 1 Yes Maybe
No No 1 No Yes
No No 1 No No
No No 1 No Maybe
No No 2 Yes Yes
No No 2 Yes No
No No 2 Yes Maybe
No No 2 No Yes
No No 2 No No
No No 2 No Maybe
No No 3 Yes Yes
No No 3 Yes No
No No 3 Yes Maybe
No No 3 No Yes
No No 3 No No
No No 3 No Maybe
No No 4 Yes Yes
No No 4 Yes No
No No 4 Yes Maybe
No No 4 No Yes
No No 4 No No
No No 4 No Maybe
No Maybe 1 Yes Yes
No Maybe 1 Yes No
No Maybe 1 Yes Maybe
No Maybe 1 No Yes
No Maybe 1 No No
No Maybe 1 No Maybe
No Maybe 2 Yes Yes
No Maybe 2 Yes No
No Maybe 2 Yes Maybe
No Maybe 2 No Yes
No Maybe 2 No No
No Maybe 2 No Maybe
No Maybe 3 Yes Yes
No Maybe 3 Yes No
No Maybe 3 Yes Maybe
No Maybe 3 No Yes
No Maybe 3 No No
No Maybe 3 No Maybe
No Maybe 4 Yes Yes
No Maybe 4 Yes No
No Maybe 4 Yes Maybe
No Maybe 4 No Yes
No Maybe 4 No No
No Maybe 4 No Maybe
```

Answer (score 2):

Using array `@c` to store indexes which are used to retrieve values from `@arr`,

```
my @arr = (
  [qw/Yes No/],
  [qw/Yes No Maybe/],
  [qw/1 2 3 4/],
  [qw/Yes No/],
  [qw/Yes No Maybe/],
);
my @c = (0) x @arr;

ITER: while (1) {
  my @comb = map $arr[$_][ $c[$_] ],  0 .. $#arr;
  print join("|", @comb), "\n";

  my $i = 0;
  ADVANCE_I: {
    if (++$c[$i] > $#{ $arr[$i] }) {
      $c[$i] =0;
      last ITER if ++$i > $#arr;
      redo ADVANCE_I;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Since you didn't ask a specific question, I assume you need help finding an algorithm?

1. For each line,

   1. Parse the line to extract the tokens.
   2. For each permutations returned by any of a number of easy-to-find functions on CPAN,

      1. Print the permutation.

If you need any help with any specific aspect, show us what you tried so we can help fix your problem.

Comment: Yes, sorry I altered my question slightly. What do you mean by 'to extra the tokens'?

Comment: @Gnippots, Typo. Should have been "extract", as in to obtain `Yes` and `No` from `Var1 [Yes|No]`.